# How to get paragraphs and shapes from word file using microsoft.office.interop.word c#

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, ms-word, office-interop

I'm trying to read the paragraph contents and shapes text from word file.
I have written following code:

```
foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Shape shape in document.Shapes)
{
    ParaInfo.Add(new ParaInfo{Text = shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text});
}

foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Paragraph para in document.Paragraphs)
{
    ParaInfo.Add(new ParaInfo{Text = para.Range.Text});
}
```

But, this will change the sequence of paragraphs and shapes. I want to get them in the same sequence as they appear in the word document.
How can I achieve this using Interop word?

Answer (score 0):

There is no sequence in Word documents and you can't get a structure as you asked. See [How to enumerate word document using office interop API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3511972/how-to-enumerate-word-document-using-office-interop-api)

The reason why you get the sequence "changed" is because you enumerate only shapes and then only tables. As you get only a text content, it might make sense to try `document.Content.Text` and see if you could build any "structure" out of it.